# Check if a specific part of a string matches another string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an input file which cannot be malformed, and I would simply like to check and see that the file is well formed before proceeding with the calculations of the program.  For this input file, reading it line by line will work, as I only need to check the very beginning of each line.

Input.txt:

```
Data1: 30
Data2: 20
Data3: 50
```

Basically, I want to read through this line by line, and check that each line begins with "Data1:" or "Data2: " or "Data3: ", and nothing else.  In other words, I can assume that what comes after those will be an integer (there is no way for it not to be, in the context of this application).  However, if the beginning of the line doesn't start with one of those, then I need to halt immediately to avoid mucking anything up.

I'm thinking I need to use the index function, and check that the index of this substring is at position 0 (ie. at the very beginning of the line).  Or, perhaps I need to use a regex.

Try Number 1:

```
if (index($str, $substr) == 0) {
    print "$str contains $substr\n";
}
```

Try Number 1 was wrong.  It was over complicating things. I should be using a regular expression here.

Try Number 2:

```
open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';
$iteration = 0
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    next if /\s*(?:#|$)/;  //Skip over lines starting with # or empty lines.
    if($iteration==0) {
        die "Error in file formatting!\n" unless /^Data1: [a-Z]+/;
        my ($data1) = /Data[1]: ([a-z0-9-]+)\s*/; 
        $iteration++;
    }
    else if($iteration==1) {
        die "Error in file formatting!\n" unless /^Data2: \d+/;
        my ($data2) = /Data[2]: (\d+)/;
        $iteration++;

    }
    else if($iteration==2) {
        die "Error in file formatting!\n" unless /^Data3: \d+/;
        my ($data3) = /Data[3]: (\d+)/;
        $iteration=0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the current line is in `$_`:

```
/^Data[123]: \d+/ or die;
```

Will check the string starts with `Data`, a digit between 1 and 3, a colon, a space and a positive integer.

If your line is in `$str`, and if you need an error message, the syntax is:

```
$str =~ /^Data[123]: \d+/ or die "Invalid line: $str";
```

If you need to extract the values, change the pattern to:

```
/^Data([123]): (\d+)/
```

The values will be in the `$1` and `$2` variables after the match.

Skipping comment lines would be as easy as:

```
next if /^\s*(?:#|$)/;
```

This will check if the first non-whitespace character of the line is a `#` or the line is empty.

Comment: Okay I'm going to take this and make another try.

Comment: I don't understand how the value gets put in the $1 and $2 variables after the match...

Comment: @Musicode If you enclose a part of the pattern in parentheses, you get *capturing groups*. Perl will put the value captured by the first parenthesized subpattern in `$1`, the second in `$2`, and so on. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for details.

Comment: @Musicode Do you need to verify that Data1 appears before Data2 and Data2 appears before Data3? If yes, then this answer won't accomplish that. It also won't protect you from Data1 (for example) appearing multiple times and Data3 not appearing at all.

Comment: @Sam Choukri Yes, I do.  Why do you think this won't accomplish this?  Each of "Data1: " "Data2: " etc are on different lines.  That is what the $iteration variable is for.  It keeps track of whether we are on the next entry yet or not.  Whenever it is equal to 0, we know that we are on to the next entry.  The goal is I want to take the data and put it in a hash, with the key coming from Data1 and the values for that key coming from Data2 and Data3.

Comment: @Musicode It appeared from your sample code that order was important so I just wanted to point out that this answer (on its own) does not enforce any particular order. Anyway, I think you're on the right track. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using an index is a messy way of achieving what I think you're after. This will read in your file, and process it line by line, exiting the loop if a line doesn't begin with either 'Data1', 'Data2' or 'Data3' (the print just illustrates the point):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

    while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    next if /^#/; # Will skip the line if it begins with #
    my ($number) = /Data[123]: (\d+)/; # Assigns the integer that follows Data1/2/3 to the scalar `$number`
    die unless /^Data[123]/; # Exit loop if line doesn't begin with Data1/2/3
    print "$number\n";
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is nice, but I have a few questions about this answer.  What if I want to skip over any commented lines in the input file?  So if a line begins with '#' I would skip over it.  Second, how would I access the integer value itself after the beginning of each line?  It seems here I would be skipping over it.